# SQLITE: unexplainable behaviour - comparison works for some numbers, not for others

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I have a query that returns a correct result, except for a few values... No idea why.
I'm using the Chinook database.

```
SELECT SUM(unitPrice)
FROM invoiceLine
WHERE invoiceId = 5
```

This returns 13,86.

```
SELECT invoiceId, total
FROM invoice 
WHERE invoiceId = 5
```

This also returns 13,86. Now consider the next query:

```
SELECT invoiceId, total
FROM invoice
WHERE total = (SELECT SUM(unitPrice)
            FROM invoiceLine
            WHERE invoiceId = 5)
```

This returns... nothing! 
When I change to *invoiceId = 1*, I do get all the results matching that amount.

Why?? 
(I know that the last query doesn't make much sense, it's simply for demonstrating the issue clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your invoice totals are correct to 2dp, you could also use

```
SELECT invoiceId, total
FROM invoice
WHERE total = (SELECT Round(SUM(unitPrice),2)
            FROM invoiceLine
            WHERE invoiceId = 5)
```

[SQL Fiddle demo (with and without round)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9cd04/3/0)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of floating point arithmetic, where what you see is not what you get.

Try something like:

```
SELECT invoiceId, total
FROM invoice i cross join
      (SELECT SUM(unitPrice) as total
            FROM invoiceLine
            WHERE invoiceId = 5
      ) i5
WHERE abs(i.total - i5.total) < 0.001
```

Comment: Your query returns all the rows, but the floating point idea has brought a solution. However, the query that I actually need is for educational purposes... A bit nasty to include all this.

    SELECT invoiceId, total
    FROM invoice
    WHERE abs(total - (SELECT SUM(unitPrice)
            FROM invoiceLine
            WHERE invoiceId = 5)) < 0.001